# Android NFC reader/writer which supports multiple NDEF records

Tags: gratis, android, nfc

I am just starting to develop an app for a friend, which requires read/write of NFC tags.

Alas, I do not have a phone that will do that yet.

He has been using [NXP Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter&hl=en) until now, and, perhaps because of that, insists that an NFC tag, when tapped, can only provoke a single action.

He is not too techy, and probably NXP writer is his whole NFC world - if it can't do it, then it can't be done.

However (to finally get to the point), things like this

[image]

from [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/beginning-nfc/9781449324094/ch04.html) convince me otherwise.

Question: does anyone (*cough* *cough* *@Izzy* *cough*) know of an Android app which will read / write NFC tags with multiple NDEF Records?

---

[Update] according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406804/2-ndef-mesages-records-on-one-nfc-tag-android), "Multiple NDEF records in one NDEF message works fine". And, since that awarded answer was posted by "[NFCguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202968/nfc-guy)", I will assume that it is correct.

So, it looks like the Android O/S supports it, although, as @Gilles points out, not all firmware might. In which case, I had better give up & seek another solution (in my case, the tag will launch an URL on my server, which will D/L an HTML page with some JS (probably [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)) which will achieve the same as if multiple NDEF records had been read. There may well be other solutions).

Comment: Some of the capabilities of NFC depend on the firmware and driver, so depending on your phone model, there may be things that no app can do. What phone do you need this for and with what Android version?

Comment: Ah, there's the rub. If I can't guarantee support on all devices, then I will need to seek an alternative :-(

Comment: As you mention me directly: I'd need to check my list of [NFC apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_nfc) for that; haven't used NFC yet myself. So now you've got the link, you might take a look for yourself :) As usual, apps with "special features" are often commented accordingly in my lists. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to try, [this app](https://www.androidpit.de/app/st.multindef) says

```
This application is designed to demonstrate that we can use ST M24SR Tag
to write multiple types of records like Text, URL , Mail, Contact , BT
Pairing HandOver Message, Wi-Fi Record in single Tag.

M24SR has enough memory that can be used to store different types of 
records in single Tag.

Application can also be used to read the M24SR Tag programmed with 
mutiple records.
```

However, given @Gilles  warning, I will pursue another solution, as stated in the updated question.